# There is a way to use less than this number of "if" There is a way to shorten this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, format

```
h = int(input ("Enter your working hours in a week:"))
rate = 8
if ((h < 0 ) or (h > 168)):
print("INVALID")
elif h <= 40:
print ("YOU MADE", rate*h, "DOLLARS THIS WEEK")
elif 41 <= h <= 50:
print("YOU MADE", int(40 * rate + (h - 40) * (1.129 * rate)), "DOLLARS THIS WEEK")
else:
```

print("YOU MADE",int(40 * rate + (h - 40) * 1.20373 * rate), "DOLLARS THIS WEEK")

Comment: `(h < 0 ) and (h > 168)` is impossible  - did you mean `or` ?

Comment: You are right, I wrote in a hurry, I mean the same or

Answer (score 1):

First(easy solution): the problem can be solved easily by just replacing 'and' operator with 'or' operator in line 3.

You can also force the user to keep entering the correct number based on your condition and also add an extra safety of checking if the entered number is an int or not by using the below code-

```
good_Input = False
while not good_Input:
    try:
        number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        if number > 0 and number < 168:
            good_Input = True
            print("that's a good number. Well done!")
        else:
            print("that's not a good number number. Try again: ")
    except ValueError:
        print("that's not an integer. Try again: ")
```

Just add this snippet in your first line and BINGOO..!!

Answer (score 0):

if ((h < 0 ) and (h > 168)):   ---------> this is wrong condition use 'or' here instead of 'and'

**check this code if it helps :**

```
h = int(input ("Enter your working hours in a week:"))
rate = 8

print((lambda: "Value is valid", lambda: "INVALID")[h < 0 or h > 168]())
print((lambda: "Hours clocked is not in range of 1 to 40 ", lambda: ("YOU MADE", rate*h, "DOLLARS THIS WEEK"))[1 < h <= 40]())
print((lambda: "Hours clocked is not in range of 41 to 50 ", lambda: ("YOU MADE", int(40 * rate + (h - 40) * (1.129 * rate)), "DOLLARS THIS WEEK"))[41 <= h <= 50]())
```

Comment: Print the decimal result
I just want the integer number to be printed on the output

Comment: i fixed it buddy , kindly look at my code , you just have to put int(output) to convert your decimal output to int .

Comment: input number 58 in your code than run it , after this put , 58 in my code and than run it , check the difference

Comment: your code will get: Enter your working hours in a week:58
YOU MADE 493.33712 DOLLARS THIS WEEK
=================

Comment: my output will get : Enter your working hours in a week:58
YOU MADE 493 DOLLARS THIS WEEK

Answer (score 0):

You can use the max and min built-in functions to avoid using ifs to determine how many hours fall into a particular range.

The number of hours eligible for overtime is the greater of `(hours - 50)` and `0`.
The number of hours eligible for standard rate pay is the lesser of `hours` and `40`.

To determine the applicable overtime rate, we can put the two rates in a tuple, with the lower rate first.  We use the result of `hours >= 50` to get the index of the required rate from the tuple.  This works because `hours >= 50` evaluates to a boolean - `True` or `False` - and booleans are subclasses of `int`, so if `hours >= 50` is `False`, the index is `0` and the lower rate is selected, otherwise the higher rate is selected.

```
rate = 8 
more = True
while more:
    h = int(input("Enter your working hours in a week:"))
    if 0 < h < 168:
        overtime_rate = (1.129, 1.20373)[h >= 50] * rate
        overtime = max(h - 40, 0) * overtime_rate
        standard_time = min(40, h) * rate
        total_pay = int(standard_time + overtime)
        print(f'YOU MADE {total_pay} DOLLARS THIS WEEK')
    else:
        print('INVALID')
    again = input('More (y/n)?').lower()
    more = (again == 'y' or again == 'yes')
```